# Linux review T background job

Tags: linux, process, jobs

```
user   23110  0.1  1.7 615392 73004 pts/2    T    20:57   0:13 process
```

I have a process what I put in the background on a terminal which froze after. Not responsive for keys/reset/commands etc.

I would like to bring this process back to the foreground from another terminal.

Is this possible to do on Debian?

When I list out jobs on other terminals I get 0 tasks, but my process is still there hanging in T state.

Comment: Have you tried `^Q`?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the command `reptyr`. You call it in the new controlling terminal with the PID of the process as argument which shall be moved to this terminal.